# Using InAppSettingsKit, how can I make it not show up in the settings app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inappsettingskit

I am using InAppSettingsKit. https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit

I want to make it so the settings panel doesn't show up in settings, because right now it does. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: Starting in iOS 8 all apps will show in the Settings app regardless of what you do.

The project page says `To support traditional Settings.app panes, the app must include a Settings.bundle with at least a Root.plist`. So if you are targeting less than iOS 8 or just don't want to allow users access to the settings via the Settings app, than removing the bundled file would be the way to go.

**UPDATE:**

I believe what you need to do is rename your Settings.bundle file so iOS doesn't pick up on it. The alternative bundle name this library picks up on is `InAppSettings.bundle` so try renaming `Settings.bundle` to `InAppSettings.bundle`.

https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit ->

> Alternatively, you can create a totally separate bundle named
>   InAppSettings.bundle instead of the usual Settings.bundle. The latter
>   approach is useful if you want to suppress the settings in
>   Settings.app.

Comment: I know all apps show up - I just want to know how I can make it so my own settings don't show up.

Comment: @benr783 Sorry but I don't think that's possible. Apple specifically puts it in there. Removing your app from there would be limiting the users control over your app.

Comment: No, I mean, I have my own settings bundle that I use with InAppSettingsKit. How can I make it so the settings that are in /there/ are not shown regular.

Comment: @benr783 So your saying that the settings bundle you have are also showing in the Settings app, correct?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to rename your settings bundle to something other than Settings.bundle.

This is from the [IASK github](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit) readme.

> In summary, the plists are searched in this order:
>
> 1. InAppSettings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.inApp.plist
> 2. InAppSettings.bundle/FILE.inApp.plist
> 3. InAppSettings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.plist
> 4. InAppSettings.bundle/FILE.plist
> 5. Settings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.inApp.plist
> 6. Settings.bundle/FILE.inApp.plist
> 7. Settings.bundle/FILE~DEVICE.plist
> 8. Settings.bundle/FILE.plist

Try using any one of the first 4 and the settings pannel shouldn't end up in the settings app.